# Validate if new range overlaps existing range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a `Range` model which has a `start_range` and an `end_range` column.

My range.rb model:

```
class Range < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :range_valid

  protected

  def range_valid
    range = Range.all
    range.each do |f|
      if (f.start_range..f.end_range).overlaps?(self.start_range..self.end_range)
        self.errors.add(:base, 'range is already alloted')
        break
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This code takes the `start_range` and `end_range`  (say 100 and 500) and matches all the database records if any range overlap (or say the two ranges must be completely exclusive ) with the range which the user have entered.

This code is working fine but this code is not feasible if there are millions of records stored in the database

Can anyone please tell me how can I match the overlapping of the range without using loop and fetching all the records by `Range.all` so that the code should be feasible for real time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily query `Range` to check if an existing range overlaps with the given range.

```
Range.where("end_date >= ?", start_of_a_range).where("start_date <= ?", end_of_a_range).count
```

To wrap this into a validator I'd first define a scope

> range.rb

```
scope :in_range, ->(range) { where("end_date >= ?", range.first).where("start_date <= ?", range.last) }
```

And then add the validator:

```
validates :range_cannot_overlap

def range_cannot_overlap
  if Range.in_range(start_range..end_range).count > 0
    errors.add(:base, 'range is already alloted')
  end
end
```

Comment: overlaps means say the two ranges must be completely exclusive .. will your answer work ?

Comment: i have very less idea about scope , what is range.first and range.last ?

Comment: [Infos about scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). `range` is an argument you pass to the scope, in this case a range. So with `range.first` you access the range start.

Comment: should also exclude self from the query. else would fail for update.  `where.not(id: id)`